# Will my baggage be checked through from LAX to PEK to ICN with Air China

Tags: luggage, beijing, air-china, pek

does anyone know if my baggage will be checked through from Los Angeles all the way to Incheon, South Korea if I’m having a layover in Beijing? My flight that lands in Beijing is in the same terminal as my flight leaving Beijing to Incheon. I’ll be flying with AirChina and don’t know if they would do that or if I’ll have to go claim my luggage and re-check it once I land in Beijing.

I had another question too about my luggage allowance, my eTicket says I have a “2 piece plan of 2 bags allowed with no fee up to 50lbs/23kg”. So does this mean that I’m allowed 2 separate checked bags in addition to my carryon?

Comment: Is this a single booking or separate tickets?

Comment: Single booking !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You luggage will be checked through in PEK but it is always best to confirm when you check in.

Yes you can have 2 separate bags plus your carry on for this flight